# List concatenation with exception

Tags: haskell, exception, undefined, lazy-evaluation

I have following expression:

```
let x = [1] ++ undefined ++ [3]
```

I 've got following exception:

```
[1*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries\base\GHC\Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:39:16 in interactive:Ghci20
```

As the counterpart to the expression above:

```
Prelude> let x = [undefined, undefined, undefined ]
Prelude> length x
```

Here, I've got as the result `3` not an exception, because values does not got evaluated until it got called.

Why the earlier expression raised an exception?

Comment: Note that those two expressions aren’t the same. Assuming `u = undefined` for brevity: `[u, u, u]` is `[u] ++ [u] ++ [u]`, not `[u] ++ u ++ [u]`. In your first example you have an undefined *list*, while in your second example you only have undefined *elements*, so `length` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write:

```
let x = [1] ++ undefined ++ [3]
```

then **`x` is not evaluated**. It is stored as an expression that has to be evaluated. But then you query `x`. In other words, you want to **`show x`**. Now **in order to show a list, the entire list (and its elements) have to be evaluated**.

Now the concat operator `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` is defined as:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
(++) [] ys = ys
```

For example `[1,2] ++ [3,4]`: will result in:

```
   [1,2] ++ [3,4]
-> 1 : ([2] ++ [3,4])
-> 1 : 2 : ([] ++ [3,4])
-> 1 : 2 : [3,4]
```

or when working with `undefined`:

```
   [1,2] ++ undefined
-> 1 : ([2] ++ undefined)
-> 1 : 2 : ([] ++ undefined)
-> 1 : 2 : undefined
```

Note that this is done *lazily*: you only concat further if you need more elements. Furthermore `(++)` does *not* care about the individual elements: if an element contains a computationally expensive operation, that operation is postponed until it is necessary to calculate it.

So as long as the first list can still emit elements, we do not care about the second list. When the end of the first list is reached, we simply return the second list.

We see that this partially works: the interpreter prints `[1*** Exception: Prelude.undefined` so in the evaluation of the `(++)` operator, the **first element of `[1]` is emitted**, evaluated and printed. But then we reach `undefined` and Haskell cannot handle it in order to print it (its elements) and terminates.

If you write `let x = [undefined,undefined,undefined]` on the other hand and you call `length x`, then **the *elements* of the list are not evaluated**. `length` is defined like:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
length [] = 0
length (_:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

mind the underscore (`_`) in the function. `length` does not care about the individual elements. It will simply walk through the list until it hits the empty list `[]`, and return that count, so `3`.

If on the other hand you would have written

```
length $ [1] ++ undefined ++ [2,3]
```

you would get the same problems:

```
Prelude> length $ [1] ++ undefined ++ [2,3]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Because in order to walk through the list, we have to concat `[1]` with `undefined`.

Comment: I can not imagine, how `++` work. Can you please expand for example `[1,2,3] ++ [3,4,5]`